# How does one refer to the game1 class's variables in XNA

Tags: c#, oop, null, xna-4.0

I try to refer to an array in the Game1 class by creating an object of the Game1 class with its definition `Game1 gameObject;` , its declaration `gameObject = new Game1();` in the constructor, and its usage `gameObject.tileArray[xInt, yInt].treed = true;`.

The game1 class itself remains unchanged in its class code other than some methods and variables. When I try to use this code in the TreeRegion class it gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object," leading me to believe that the game1 class is null somehow.

How might one change the class or object in order to refer to game1's variables? Mind you I am self-taught and still rather new to C#.

The class that refers to game1:
http://pastebin.com/0chEcKfq
Game1 itself
http://pastebin.com/zLDVzCca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to use this code in the TreeRegion class it gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object," leading me to believe that the game1 class is null somehow.

Not necessary. Look at your expression:

```
gameObject.tileArray[xInt, yInt].treed = true;
```

That will throw a `NullReferenceException` if *any* of these are true:

- `gameObject` is null (unlikely, given the code you've shown)
- `gameObject.tileArray` is null
- `gameObject.tileArray[xInt, yInt]` is null

You haven't shown us the `Game1` class - it seems very likely that either the second or third bullet is the problem here.

You should probably consider whether this should actually be part of the `Game1` API rather than digging down the level like this:

```
game1.MakeTree(xInt, yInt);
```

... or whatever the better name might be. It certainly looks like you're missing some encapsulation here.

(Personally I wouldn't really recommend learning C# via something like XNA. I think while you're still at the stage of learning the language and core libraries, it's a better idea to work in a simple environment such as console applications. I realize they may seem boring, but a bit of groundwork up-front may make a huge different in the long run.)

EDIT: Now we can see `Game1` (which could do with a new name - and you should try to follow the [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx)) I strongly suspect that `createTiles` is causing the problem. It's not at all obvious that that will *actually* populate every element of `tileArray` - particularly as you never even use `a` or `b`. My guess is that `gameObject.tileArray[xInt, yInt]` is returning `null` in your `TreeRegion` code.

EDIT: Looking at how you're creating the array, it's even more concerning:

```
gridWidth = 100; gridHeight = 100;
gridScope = gridWidth * gridHeight;
tileArray = new Tile[gridScope, gridScope];
```

Did you *really* want a 10000x10000 array? Are you sure you need this `gridScope`? I would have expected:

```
tileArray = new Tile[gridWidth, gridHeight];
```

Note that in `createTiles` you're only populating *at most* `gridHeight * gridWidth` elements (i.e. ten *thousand* out of the ten *million* elements in the array).

Comment: it is indeed the array that is null, as I can still ascess other variables in the class

Comment: the array is declared and defined, it is used in the createTiles method

Comment: @user1149068: See my edit at the bottom. I don't think it's the array that's null - I suspect it's one of the elements *within* the array.

Comment: every variable within the game1 object is null.

Comment: @user1149068: Is *anything* calling `Initialize`? That's where the tile array is populated...

Comment: On this link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.initialize.aspx It says that Initialize() as well as Update() and Draw() will be called automatically because its xna. 
My problem now is that I am trying to pass a reference of the Game1 object into each constructor of the treeRegion class but I do not know how to set a variable equal to the current game1 object without creating a new one. I defined a game1 variable above the initialize() with `Game1 parentGame1; `, but I do not know how to set that variable so that it is the object of the Game1 class.

Comment: @user1149068: If everything within `game1` is null, that suggests that `Initialize()` *hasn't* been run. It could well be that it would be run in "normal" cases, but that you're not meant to just call the constructor and use the object like this... is even `graphics` null? That would be *very* strange.

Comment: @user1149068: I've just read the link you posted. It says "If this GameComponent has been added to the Game.Components collection, this method will be called automatically if you call base.Initialize in your Game.Initialize method." - There's no indication that you're adding it to `Game.Components`, or that you're calling `Initialize()` within `Game.Initialize()`. Basically, you almost certainly *shouldn't* be creating a UI object and using it in this way.

Comment: @user1149068: I have no idea *which* instance of `Game1` you're referring to though - or what constructs a TreeRegion. You should take all of this as a hint that your design is too complicated, and that you should take a step back and simplify it.

Comment: If I shouldn't be creating this type of user interface this way then what is the right way. What would you suggest for me to change?

Comment: @user1149068: It's hard to redesign your app just based on two classes - especially as I haven't used XNA myself - but creating a visual component from within a non-visual class seems like a bad idea.

Comment: The treeRegion merely produces a list of coordinates that gets passed to the tileArray to make true a bunch of Bools of a bunch of Tiles true. I want to be able to manipulate an array in my Game1.cs from my treeRegion.cs. How is this done? I'm currently trying to send a variable of the game1 object to the treeRegion.

Comment: @user1149068: Yes, you could pass it as a parameter to the constructor of `TreeRegion` - but you've given us no indication of where `TreeRegion` is constructed...

Comment: Its constructed in the createTrees(). How would I declare the Game1 object without creating a new one.

Comment: @user1149068: Just add another parameter of type `Game1` to the `TreeRegion` constructor, and pass in `this` as the argument from `Game1`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wonderful debugger built into Visual Studio.

Though I cannot tell with out the Game1 code, I would assume that the array your are accessing is null.

gameObject.tileArray needs to be instanciated in the GameObject Constructor

so

```
Game1()
{
    tileArray = new Tile[]();

}
```

Assuming Tile is the class that is in the array.

Comment: We've got `Game1` now - the tile array looks like it's non-null, but I believe one of the *elements* is still null.